# What is a more efficient way of checking for width when using the jQuery UI resizable tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am making a site with a resizable sidebar. When the user resizes this sidebar, I would like the icons and text in the sidebar to shrink with the sidebar. Currently I am using `if` statement to check if the sidebar's width is below a certain size, but when I look on my Mac's Activity Monitor it shows that there is a lot of strain going on in Chrome when I continually resize the sidebar. My solution works, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about this. This is what I'm working with:

HTML:

```
<div id = "home_left">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/image1.jpg" id = "profile_picture"/></a>
    <p id = "profile_username">username</p>
    <div class = "icon_container">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image2.png" class = "profile_icons"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "icon_container">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image3.png" class = "profile_icons"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "icon_container">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image4.png" class = "profile_icons"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Setting the left sidebar as resizable
    $("#home_left").resizable({
        handles: "e",
        maxWidth: $("#home_left").width(),
        minWidth: 100,
        resize: function() {
            //Width of profile picture
            $("#profile_picture").width($("#home_left").width() - 24);

            //Appearance of username and icons
            if($("#home_left").width() < 200) {
                $("#profile_username").addClass("hidden");
                $(".icon_container").width($("#home_left").width());
            }
            else {
                $("#profile_username").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpjb19m7/

It doesn't show as much CPU usage in the Fiddle because there are no images being resized, but you can still see that there is a great deal more strain on the browser than usual. Is this just how jQuery UI is or am I doing something inefficiently?

Comment: your fiddle seems to be broken!

Comment: @Vickel What is broken in my Fiddle? I clicked the link and it seems fine to me

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Resizable Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable), you will notice that you can bind callbacks not only for the `resize` event (which I guess it's the source of the strain you notice, since that's gonna fire continuously) but also for `start` and `stop` events.

I guess listening for those events can solve your problem, if you need your sidebar UI to be responding only on the begin/end of a resize operation.